# DeploymentItem (mdf-File) and Connection String

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, mstest

I'm working with Visual Studio Testing Tools, and I'd like to write some database tests. Therefor I added a `Data\Test.mdf` file to my solution, and added a `DeploymentItemAttribute` to my test:

```
[DeploymentItem("\\Data\\Test.mdf")]
```

The test project has a Connection String Setting to, which looks like this:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=.\Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

The file is deployed to the test output directory. It's not found, however. SQL Server uses a different root directory. I'm struggling to find it. I cannot change it at runtime, since an ASP.NET membership provider is involved.

I get the following `SqlException` on `SqlConnection.Open`:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file .\Test.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot
>   be opened, or it is located on UNC share.